# Deserializing xml namespaces with Jackson & Kotlin

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a xml element with 2 namespaces, and I'm not able to read them with jackson.

```xml
<Person xmlns="http://some.namespace.com" xmlns:ns0="http://some.other.namespace.com">
    <name>John</name>
</Person>
```

```
internal data class Person(
    val name: String,
    @get:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    val xmlns: String,
    @get:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName="xmlns:ns0")
    val ns0: String
)
```

When reading the XML with jackson, I get an error saying that both namespaces should be nullable.

I've tried with some variants like attrs in the body of the class and with the namespace attribute, like

```
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "ns0", namespace = "xmlns")
    var ns0: String? = null
```

This is the mapper I'm using

```
val mapper: XmlMapper = XmlMapper().apply {
        registerModule(KotlinModule())
        setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    }
```

How can I read and write again this xml and make them identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem setting a property to the XMLInputFactory like this:

```
val inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory()
inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false)
XmlMapper(inputFactory).apply {
   registerModule(KotlinModule())
}
```

In this case you can model all the namespaces and do what you want.
Case solved.

Answer (score 1):

The XML parameters `xmlns="...."` and `xmlns:prefix="...."`
are XML namespace definitions. They are not XML attributes,
even if they look like this.

Hence, you must not define POJO attributes corresponding to the these.
Instead, you use the `namespace` parameter of [`@JacksonXmlProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html). 
So your `Person` class will simply look like this:

```
internal data class Person(
    @get: JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true, localName="name", namespace="http://some.namespace.com")
    val name: String
)
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but the `ns0` namespace would disappear if I write the xml back. I don't control the xml and I need it to have the same namespaces.

Comment: In your XML input example the `ns0` namespace prefix is not used anywhere. Therefore it doesn't matter, that it doesn't appear in the XML output. If the XML input would actually use it (for example by `<ns0:name>John</ns0:name>`), then it would also appear in the XML output.

Comment: I understand, buy in my case that ns is needed by the target system (because there's an attribute that contains the ns (like `<name type="ns0:something">John</name>`). I know it doesn't make xml sense but I can't control either the source xml or the needs of the target system. Is there a way to force the ns despite not being used?