# How to write and read a XML file in kotlin?

Tags: arrays, xml, kotlin

I am writing a WearOs application but I'm pretty new to Kotlin. The problem is I need to read and write Arrays to an XML file. I really don't know how to do this. The whole thing should look something like this:

```
if (xmlFileIsPresent){
  //read or write from File
}else{
//create
}
```

And in the XML Document I just want to store arrays.

The whole code should just check is there is a file present, if there is one then just read or modify the data from it. But if there is no file then a new file should be created.

Comment: For file operations on the JVM there is kotlin.io https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/. For working with XML files there is Kotlin serialization https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/tree/master with XML functionality https://github.com/pdvrieze/xmlutil

Comment: If the native IO capability doesn't suit your purpose, consider external library Jackson (https://stackoverflow.com/q/56318980/1847378)

Comment: As AndrewL indicates, a 3rd-party library is the usual way to approach this.  In Kotlin/JVM [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/) is the one I tend to see (along with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for JSON), though I don't know whether that would be applicable to WearOS.